# Change port for Desktop sharing in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: vnc

I was looking to change the port in Ubuntu 12.10 for Desktop sharing. I've done it before but have since clean installed and can't remember where to change it. It was an interface similar to gconf-editor.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool is `dconf-editor`. Install it by installing the `dconf-tools` package from the repositories. Open it, and navigate to `desktop.gnome.remote-access`.

[image: vino port]

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to check the "use-alternative-port" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do

```
vncserver -rfbport 12345
```

where `12345` is any port you desire